# Better way of dealing with a MYSQL SELECT query on a id that can also be nil

Tags: go

Is there a better way of dealing with a MYSQL SELECT query on a id that can also be nil. The code below works, but I would like to have it in one query. Is that possible?

```
    if parent_id != nil {
        err := db.QueryRow("SELECT id FROM category WHERE parent_id = ?", parent_id).Scan(&category_id)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ID not found", err)
        }
    } else {
        err := db.QueryRow("SELECT id FROM category WHERE parent_id is NULL").Scan(&category_id)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ID not found", err)
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to return all records that match the parent_id value, and all null records with a null parent_d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [NULL-safe equal to operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```golang
err := db.QueryRow(`SELECT id
    FROM category
    WHERE parent_id <=> ?
`, parent_id).Scan(&category_id)
```

---

As an alternative, you could, inside the SQL, test the passed in Go argument twice (you'll have to pass it twice):

1. do a plain equality comparison against the column.
2. check if the parameter *and* the column are both `NULL`.

```golang
err := db.QueryRow(`SELECT id
    FROM category
    WHERE parent_id = ?
    OR (? IS NULL AND parent_id IS NULL)
`, parent_id, parent_id).Scan(&category_id)
```